# UWP: how to optimize synchronization between WCF WebServices and SQLite through async calls

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, synchronization, async-await

I must synchronize data coming from **WCF WebServices** in a **SQLite database**.
This synchronization represents a dozen of WebServices, that can be "grouped" in 4 categories:

- "**User's**" Rights
- "**Forms**" data, which can be updated from the two sides (user/server)
- "**Server**" data, which are only updated from the server
- "**Views**" data, wich copy locally the views of the server

Each call to the WebService is done through **HttpClient**:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(webServiceName, content);
```

Each WebService has its own **async method** where the WebService response is **deserialized**:

```
public static async Task<string> PushForm(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
{
    var response = await JsonParser.GetJsonFromUrl(WebServiceName.PushForm.Value, parameters);
    Forms forms = new Forms();
    try
    {
        forms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Forms>(response);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Then I have a **SynchronizationService** class, where I regroup the calls to WebServices by categories:

```
public async Task<bool> SynchronizeServerData()
{
    bool result = false;
    try
     {
        result = true;
        List<Table1> tables1 = await WebServices.GetListTable1(null);
        if (tables1 != null)
        {
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().DeleteAll<Table1>(true);
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().AddAll<Table1>(tables1);
        }
        List<Table2> tables2 = await WebServices.GetListTable2(null);
        if (tables2 != null)
        {
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().DeleteAll<Table2>(true);
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().AddAll<Table2>(tables2);
        }
        List<Table3> tables3 = await WebServices.GetListTable3(null);
        if (tables3 != null)
        {
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().DeleteAll<Table3>(true);
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().AddAll<Table3>(tables3);
        }
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And finally, in the **main ViewModel**, I call each of these methods:

```
public async void SynchronizeData(bool firstSync)
{
    IsBusy = true;
    var resUsers = await _synchronisation.SynchronizeUsersRights();
    var resServer = await  _synchronisation.SynchronizeServerData();
    var resForm = await _synchronisation.SynchronizeForms();
    var resViews = await _synchronisation.SynchronizeViews();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

But due to the use of "await" the performance is not good.

***=> I would like to know if there is an easy way to "parallelize" the calls to optimize performance? Or is it possible to separate the data recovery from the SQLite update for this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it there appear to be opportunities to run a few things concurrently, for instance in `SynchronizeData` you could do this instead:

```
{
    IsBusy = true;
    Task resUsersTask = _synchronisation.SynchronizeUsersRights();
    Task resServerTask = _synchronisation.SynchronizeServerData();
    Task resFormTask = _synchronisation.SynchronizeForms();
    Task resViewsTask = _synchronisation.SynchronizeViews();
    await Task.WhenAll(resUsersTask, resServerTask, resFormTask, resViewsTask);
    var resUsers = resUsersTask.Result;
    var resServer = resServerTask.Result;
    var resForm = resFormsTask.Result;
    var resViews = resViewsTask.Result;       
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

...which would allow those 4 tasks to run concurrently.

You could do the same in `SynchronizeServerData`; e.g.:

```
result = true;
Task tables1Task = WebServices.GetListTable1(null);
Task tables2Task = WebServices.GetListTable2(null);
Task tables3Task = WebServices.GetListTable3(null);

List<Table1> tables1 = await tables1Task;
// ...

List<Table2> tables2 = await tables2Task;
// ...

List<Table3> tables3 = await tables3Task;
// ...
```

This would allow the 3 tasks to run concurrently as well.

How much you actually gain from this might depend on things like does SQLite allow you to do multiple concurrent requests - I don't know the answer to that offhand.

Some other comments:

```
public async void SynchronizeData(bool firstSync)
```

`async void` is almost always incorrect, except for event handlers and rare fire-and-forget methods, and usually `async Task` is what you want.  Search SO for any number of good answers on why.

Then lastly, what you really should do is profile the code to see where your real bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
But is there a way to know the "result" of an async Task call through the Task.WhenAll() ?
I need to know this result and notify the user if the sync failed.

Comment: Yes; see the docs on [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you prefer, you can also create the Tasks first (as I showed in the SynchronizeServerData example), then examine each result, e.g. with task.Result, after WhenAll() completes.

Comment: BTW as I kinda omitted the results retrieval initially, I've adjusted the answer to reflect a way to do it.  If you had many tasks you would probably use a collection instead, but with just 4 it's easy-enough that way.

Comment: Thanks again! I have also a question about the manage of the Exceptions across the different levels of the calls during the synchronization. I would like notify the user on the encountered exception (wrong password, timeout, lost connection, ...) but I must also pass "null" results for continuing the synchronization in some cases. Is there a proper way to doing this?

Comment: When you use await you can catch exceptions that the called code throws at the same level as the await.  When you use Task.WhenAll() you still get access to all the exceptions thrown in all the tasks, either (or both) as an AggregateException from WhenAll() in the case of awaiting Tasks that return results, or by inspecting each Task (.TaskStatus, .Exception) after WhenAll() completes.  I'm not sure what you mean about "passing null results" - if it's not specific to this question you should probably create a new question to avoid us straying off topic here.

Comment: I've created a dedicated topic as you suggest me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718376/uwp-how-to-manage-exceptions-during-a-synchronization